# Rewrite URL for results of a custom WP_Query

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting

I have this form:

```
<form action="<?php the permalink(); ?>" method="get" >
<input type="hidden" name="taxo" value="question" />
<select name = "cata">
  <option value='unique_name-a'>xxx</option>
  <option value='foo'>yyy</option>
  <option value='bar'>zzz</option>
</select>
<select name ="catb">
  <option value='unique_name-d'>xxx</option>
  <option value='unique_name-e'>yyy</option>
  <option value='unique_name-f'>zzz</option>
</select>
<!-- and more select -->
<button>send</button>
</form>
```

And this query in a template page:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
  'post_type' =>  'page',
  'tax_query' => array(                   
    'relation' => 'AND',                     
      array(
        'taxonomy' => 'question',   // from $_GET['taxo']            
        'field' => 'slug',                   
        'terms' => array('unique_name-a','unique_name-e','more'), // from my submit form   
        'include_children' => false,          
        'operator' => 'AND'                    
      ),
  )
) );
```

I would like to play with URL rewriting. I have something like:

```
http://example.com/?taxo=question&cata=foo&catb=bar&catc=more
```

I would like the rewritten URL for the above query to be:

```
http://example.com/questions/cata/foo/catb/bar/catc/…/
```

EDIT: Why this function is not working?

```
  function custom_rewrite() {
       add_rewrite_rule(
        'question-tax/test/4/',
        'index.php?tax=question&test=4',
        'top'
        );

      }
      // refresh/flush permalinks in the dashboard if this is changed in any way
      add_action( 'init', 'custom_rewrite' );
```

Comment: And your research so far has come up with what?

Comment: I read this : https://thereforei.am/2011/10/28/advanced-taxonomy-queries-with-pretty-urls/, https://carlalexander.ca/wordpress-adventurous-rewrite-api/ and http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/75258/how-to-rewrite-custom-post-type-url-for-multiple-depths-instead-of-one-specific. I added this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/.

Comment: @benoît I see you want `/catc/catc/` to be shown up twice in the rewritten URL, is that correct? Or do you want it to be `/catc/more/`?

Comment: Has this question been resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the [add_rewrite_endpoint](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint) function, which would actually let you avoid any htaccess modification (unless you need $_GET).

Example:

```
function add_custom_rewrite_ep() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint('cata', EP_PAGES);
    add_rewrite_endpoint('catb', EP_PAGES);
    add_rewrite_endpoint('catc', EP_PAGES);
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_custom_rewrite_ep' );
```

**Make sure you flush your rewrite rules.**

So then, if your URL is `/questions/cata/foo/catb/bar/catc/more/`, you can access the values with `get_query_var` like so:

```
$x = get_query_var('cata','default'); // equals 'foo'
$y = get_query_var('catb','default'); // equals 'bar'
$z = get_query_var('catc','default'); // equals 'more'
```

It is difficult though to give you an exact solution without knowing how your url's are generated, if you're using the $_GET global, and how you're using the values in your code.

Comment: I use a form `<form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" method="get">…</form>`  in a custom template page. I add your code, but don't know how to deal with it (I flush my rewrite rules).

Comment: Please post all of your code as an edit to your question. There's no way to tell you how to fix your issue with only tiny pieces of the puzzle. :)

Comment: I try  `add_rewrite_endpoint` `questions/cata/foo/catb/bar/catc/more/` is not 404 but ugly url works too `/?taxo=question&cata=foo&catb=bar&catc=more/?taxo=question&cata=foo&catb=bar&catc=more` and stay ugly.

I make a test with this example : https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule#Using_Custom_Templates_with_custom_querystring (Template Name: Nutritional Information) 
and I have the same issue with the ugly url (stay ugly).

Comment: I found some documentations to complete the official codex : 
http://hardcorewp.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/hardcore-urls-wcatl2014.pdf (most complete)
https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/the-rewrite-api-the-basics--wp-25474 (clear)
https://www.pmg.com/blog/a-mostly-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-rewrite-api/

Comment: So did you get it to work?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my approach to it using the following `RewriteRule` in the `.htaccess` instead of using the `add_rewrite_rule()` function:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^taxo=([^&]+)&([^=]+)=([^&]+)&([^=]+)=([^&]+)&([^=]+)=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/?$ /%1/%2/%3/%4/%5/%6/%7? [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

This has been tested and verified using the [htaccess tester](http://htaccess.mwl.be/).

The difference between [Spartacus'](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/32329) answer and mine is that condition is met if the query string has `?taxo=` in it before it starts the rewrite rule. Also, my rewrite isn't bound to only `cata`, `catb`, and `catc` which you are using for example purposes. This rule dynamically covers all of your other slugs, in case your taxonomy values were to change. For example:

```
http://example.com/?taxo=question&cata=foo&catb=bar&catc=more
http://example.com/?taxo=answer&type=foo&id=123&date=123
```

Will become:

```
http://example.com/question/cata/foo/catb/bar/catc/more
http://example.com/answer/type/foo/id/123/date/123
```

Comment: It's work, but if someone flush the rewrite rules, I need to rewrite the htaccess. The next step is to add this rule with WordPress function. And I have another problem, I did not anticipate my  _action_ to get query results in a custom page`<form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" method="get">…</form>`, I don't know how to deal with my permalink `http://example.com/mypagename/?taxo=…` 
I try `RewriteRule ^mypagename/?$ /%1/%2/%3/%4/%5/%6/%7? [L,R=301]`.

Comment: If you add your custom rewrite rules outside `#BEGIN WordPress` `#END WordPress`, your rewrite rules will not be erase with a flush rewrite. WordPress only touch what is inside these tags.

Comment: @benoît Update my answer based on Benoti's comment.

Comment: @EthanJinksO'Sullivan it's work but WordPress can't find the page (404). This is the part 1 of the answer. The Spartacus's answer is another part 1 of the answer, but I think I can find the part 2 (rewriting my form and my functions.php).

Comment: @benoît I've updated my answer to explain the difference between Spartacus' answer and mine. May you update your question to elaborate on what you're trying to achieve in "part 2"?